# How to check if the passed object is on the map

Tags: java

In the method `public boolean onMap(Coord c)` how can I figure out if the given `Coord` c is on this `Map` (`Map` is also a class)? Both of the classes are below.

```
 import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Map {

        Spot[][] floorPlan;
        Thing[] things;
        java.io.PrintStream log;

        Map(String fileName, PrintStream log) throws IOException
        {
        String line = "";
        int cols = 0;
        int rows = 0;
        Scanner data = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        while(data.hasNextLine())
        {
            line = data.nextLine();
            cols = line.length();
            rows++;
        }
        floorPlan = new Spot[rows][cols];
        }


        public boolean onMap(Coord c)
        {


            return true;
        }
    }


    public class Coord {

        public final int r;
        public final int c;


        public Coord(int r, int c)
        {
            this.r = r;
            this.c = c;
        }

        public Coord step(Direction d)
        {
            if(d == Direction.N)
            {
                Coord newValue = new Coord(r + 1, c);
                return newValue;
            }
            else if(d == Direction.S)
            {
                Coord newValue = new Coord(r - 1, c);
                return newValue;
            }
            else if(d == Direction.E)
            {
                Coord newValue = new Coord(r, c + 1);
                return newValue;
            }
            else if(d == Direction.W)
            {
                Coord newValue = new Coord(r, c - 1);
                return newValue;
            }

            else
                return this;

        }

        public Coord copy()
        {
            Coord clone = new Coord(r, c);
            return clone;

        }

        public boolean equals(Object o)
        {
            if(o instanceof Coord)
            {
                Coord newValue = (Coord)o;
                return this.r == newValue.r && this.c == newValue.c;
            }
            else 
                return false;
        }

        public boolean adjacent(Coord other)
        {
            Coord temp1 = new Coord(r + 1, c);
            Coord temp2 = new Coord(r - 1, c);
            Coord temp3 = new Coord(r, c + 1);
            Coord temp4 = new Coord(r, c - 1);

            if(temp1.r == other.r && temp1.c == other.c)
                return true;
            else if(temp2.r == other.r && temp2.c == other.c)
                return true;
            else if(temp3.r == other.r && temp3.c == other.c)
                return true;
            else if(temp4.r == other.r && temp4.c == other.c)
                return true;
            else 
                return false;

        }

        public String toString()
        {
            return String.format("\"@(%d,%d)\"", r,c);
        }


    }
```

Comment: I cannot see any `Coord` instance stored inside your `Map` class. How do you expect to find a `Coord` then?

Comment: What does "belongs to" mean?

Comment: You need to add functionality to the `Map` class so that you can add `Coord` objects to it.  Add methods for this, and variables to keep track of which `Coord` have been added.  Then in your `onMap` method you can check your local variables to determine whether the `Coord` is present.

Answer (score 0):

A guess in the blue is that you want to do something called bounds checking. (Tell me if not so)

Since a `Spot[][]` is an array of arrays, `floorPlan[i]` is actually another array (with independent bounds). Thus to check if

```
floorPlan[r][c]
```

will not throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, you need to first bound-check `r` on `floorPlan` and then `c`on `floorPlan[r]`:

```
if (r < 0 || r >= floorPlan.length) return false;
if (c < 0 || c >= floorPlan[r].length) return false;
return true;
```

However it may be more natural to actually give `Map` the properties `width` and `height` and enforce `floorPlan[r].length = width` and `floorPlan.length = height` at all times. For better code you shouldn't make the private variables available from outside the class, but instead provide sensible getters and setters (maybe even functionality to resize the `Map` without losing its content?)